# Rotas SpringBoot e Angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Estou tentando colocar url amigável pra tirar o '#' da url do angular, segui o seguinte tutorial: [/spring-boot-as-a-backend-for-angularjs/](http://info.michael-simons.eu/2014/04/15/spring-boot-as-a-backend-for-angularjs/)

e deu certo nas url estatica. Porém se eu fizer isso

```
  .state('site3.evento', {//angular
              url: '/evento/:informacaoEventoId',
              templateUrl: 'tpl-site/evento.html',

//Java
@RequestMapping(/evento/{informacaoEventoId})
public String evento() {
    return "forward:index.html";
}

@Override//Spting
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(
            "/resources/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("/");

}
```

Como o id é dinâmico ai da erro, ele não consegue exibir a página o erro é esse:

```
o.s.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter     : Cannot forward to error page for request [/evento/208] as the response has already been committed. As a result, the response may have the wrong status code. If your application is running on WebSphere Application Server you may be able to resolve this problem by setting com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.invokeFlushAfterService to false
```

Controller

```
@Controller
public class RouteController implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@RequestMapping({
    "/",
    "/contato",
    "/politica-de-privacidade",
    "/quem-somos",
    "/termo-de-uso",
    "/faq/teste"
})
public String index() {
    return "forward:index.html";
}

@RequestMapping("/evento/{informacaoEventoId}")
public String evento(@PathVariable String informacaoEventoId) {
    return "forward:index.html";
}
```

}

Spring

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan  
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {  

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(
        SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.default",
            System.getProperty("spring.profiles.default", "dev"));
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    final ApplicationContext applicationContext = SpringApplication.run(
            Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

O erro que estou vendo é a falta da definição do parametro *informacaoEventoId* no método `evento`. Ele deve ser anotado com `@PathVariable`

O código dever ficar assim:

```
@RequestMapping(/evento/{informacaoEventoId})
public String evento(@PathVariable String informacaoEventoId) {
    return "forward:index.html";
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz dessa maneira e também não funcionou, o forward é sempre pro index.html se fosse apenas /faq o forward seria pro index.html também por causa do angular, porém quando tenho que colocar um id tipo evento/208 ai vem o erro.

Comment: Mas o erro é o mesmo quando você coloca o param no método?

Comment: não, o erro é outro, mas verifiquei aqui era isso mesmo, tenho que colocar o param, sendo q ai fiz outro teste com uma url estatica, coloquei
faq/teste e mapei tanto no angular como no java, e o erro é o mesmo. Acho que o problema ta na configuração do Spring, editei a pergunta e coloquei o metodo do spring. vlw

Comment: Mostra como está a classe `Controller`, e como vc a chama.

Pq o SpringBoot basicamente não precisa se configurado, evitando assim um monte de complicações.

Comment: Tenta não seguir o tutorial, ou faz por parte. assim vc pode achar o erro. Eu até que queria depurar esse código, mas sem muito tempo agora.

vc quer passar pra mim o código do server(claro, remova as tuas regras de negocio e detahes de banco, essas coisa...)

Comment: vlw andré, estou não seguindo o tutorial como vc informou, alterei a classe Application pro padrão do spring-boot, realmente eu tava usando muita coisa que não era necessária pois o spring-boot ja vem todo configurado, mas não consegui resolver ainda, pelo menos to tendo novas idéias de como fazer. vlw